# SQL sum colum with the oldest lines

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select rows from a table without exceeding the sum total of 5000 euros starting with the oldest lines.
Select id, arrival_date, company_name, cost, address from table where state = 'F' and sum (cost) =< 5000 order by arrival date;
How to display the lines without exceeding the cost of 5000 euros? example below :

```
7;2003;soso;1000;Rue …;F
4;2004;jaja;3000;Rue …;F
6;2008;mama;500 ;Rue …;F
5;2009;lala;500 ;Rue …;F
```

Table :

```
id  Date    Company Cost Address    STATE
1   2017    Toto    2000    Rue …   F
2   2019    vava    1000    Rue …   F
3   2008    tata    4000    Rue …   F
4   2004    jaja    3000    Rue …   F
5   2009    lala    500 Rue …   F
6   2008    mama    500 Rue …   F
7   2003    soso    1000    Rue …   F
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: When you ask a question, always include your Oracle version (complete number, for example 11.2.0.4.0 - use `select banner from v$version` and see what it reports). For example, your problem has an elegant and efficient solution using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`, but that is only available in versions 12.1 and higher.

Comment: A few more questions for you. First, your "date" is actually just the year. Is that so in your real data? Then: if two (or more) rows are in the same year (have the same "date"), in what order do you need to select those rows? Finally, a big question. In your example, you have **two** rows for year 2008. In your output, you don't select `'tata'`, with a very high cost; but you **do** go on to pick the row from 2009, which still keeps the sum under 5000. Is that the actual requirement, or is it a mistake? Gordon Linoff offered an answer that treats that as a **mistake**, not desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(cost) over (order by date) as running_cost
      from t
      where state = 'F'
     ) t
where running_cost <= 5000;
```

If `date` is really a year that has duplicates, then you probably want a tie-breaker for the ordering:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(cost) over (order by date, id ) as running_cost
      from t
      where state = 'F'
     ) t
where running_cost <= 5000;
```

Comment: Inspecting the OP's "desired output", we see that he selects one row with "date" 2008. He does **not** select the other row also from 2008 (it would make the sum exceed 5000), but he **does**, then include the row from 2009. If that is the desired behavior (rather than simply a mistake on the OP's part - I asked him to clarify), then this solution won't give the desired result.

Comment: I see that you modified your answer slightly. It still doesn't address the issue I raised (which wasn't simply the non-deterministic order). If a row is discarded because it makes the running total greater than 5000, but then **further rows are still considered**, then the problem doesn't have a simple solution based on analytic sum.

Comment: @mathguy . . . Now I see what you are saying.  I missed that.  You are right.  This is then  a bin-packing problem, and that is not really amenable to a SQL-based solution.

Comment: The OP still needs to confirm that my reading is correct. It is also possible that he made a mistake with that "desired output". With that said - the problem is not really a bin-packing problem; and bin-packing problems **are** solvable in Oracle SQL (for example with the `match_recognize` clause, but it can also be done in older versions of Oracle).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your "desired output" is correct, the problem is interesting. You don't simply keep a running total and stop when the sum exceeds 5000. Rather, it seems that you order the rows by date (and then, presumably, by cost if the date is the same), then you consider the rows in order, one at a time, and you either retain them in the output or you discard them, depending on whether adding that row keeps the running total of **selected** rows below 5000 or it makes it bigger than 5000.

This is how you end up selecting `lala` (from 2009) even though you discarded `tata` from 2008. Is that correct?

Assuming it is, the problem has a simple, elegant and efficient solution using `match_recognize`. This requires Oracle version 12.1 or higher.

The `WITH` clause is not part of the solution (remove it, and use your actual table name and column names). I included it just for testing. Also: **DATE** is an Oracle keyword, which should not be used as column name. I used **DATE_** instead (with a trailing underscore).

```
with
  test_data (id, date_, company, cost, address, state) as (
    select 1, 2017, 'Toto', 2000, 'Rue ...', 'F' from dual union all
    select 2, 2019, 'vava', 1000, 'Rue ...', 'F' from dual union all
    select 3, 2008, 'tata', 4000, 'Rue ...', 'F' from dual union all
    select 4, 2004, 'jaja', 3000, 'Rue ...', 'F' from dual union all
    select 5, 2009, 'lala',  500, 'Rue ...', 'F' from dual union all
    select 6, 2008, 'mama',  500, 'Rue ...', 'F' from dual union all
    select 7, 2003, 'soso', 1000, 'Rue ...', 'F' from dual
  )
select id, date_, company, cost, address, state
from   test_data
match_recognize(
  order by date_, cost
  all rows per match
  pattern ( (a|{-b-})* )
  define  a as sum(a.cost) <= 5000
);

ID DATE_      COMPANY       COST ADDRESS STATE
-- ---------- ------- ---------- ------- -----
 7 2003       soso          1000 Rue ... F
 4 2004       jaja          3000 Rue ... F
 6 2008       mama           500 Rue ... F
 5 2009       lala           500 Rue ... F
```

For older Oracle versions (starting from 10.1), you can use the `MODEL` clause. Not as elegant or as efficient as `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`, but it will do the job. The assumptions, and the test data (and output), are the same as above.

```
select id, date_, company, cost, address, state
from   (
         select *
         from   (select t.*, row_number() over (order by date_, cost) as rn 
                 from test_data t)
         model
           dimension by (rn)
           measures  (id, date_, company, cost, address, state,
                      0 r_sum, 0 flag)
           rules automatic order (
             flag [any] = case when nvl(r_sum[cv() - 1], 0) + cost[cv()] <= 5000 
                               then 1 else 0 end,
             r_sum[any] = nvl(r_sum[cv() - 1], 0)
                          + case flag[cv()] when 1 then cost[cv()] else 0 end
           )
       )
where  flag = 1
;
```

Comment: I am on a base Oral 11g, so I tried the 2nd request but I have this error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected% s got% s "

Comment: @DavidOl - It works fine for me. The error message should also show you the line of code and the precise position on that line where the error was found - what does that say? Most likely, the data type of your columns is not what one would expect. (For example, you would get that error if the `cost` column was `varchar2` instead of `number`.) You can find the data type of each column with the `describe` column, for example `describe <table_name>` - run that on your table and see what data type each column has.

Comment: Yes, it is a VARCHAR2 (200 BYTE), how to do it?

Comment: error line is 14 + case flag[cv()] when 1 then cost[cv()] else 0 end

Comment: @DavidOl - OK, that is easy to fix (see below); but - if I may ask - is this a production system? With a `cost` column in VARCHAR2 data type? **Why?** Who designed it that way? In any case - the fix: Find the `measures (id, .... )` line in the code, and in that line, find `cost`. Replace that with `to_number(cost) as cost` (and leave everything else unchanged).

Comment: This is a table that has been in existence for years, it is used by other applications too, I do not know why it was designed like that, I test in the day and I come back to you if needed, thank you very much

Comment: @DavidOl - Please read my instruction in the earlier comment. Do you see what you missed? You made the change in the `SELECT` clause. You have to undo that change. Then find the `MEASURES` clause (in the `MODEL` part of the query) and make the change **there**. And don't just use `to_number()` - make the change **exactly** as I instructed.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your answer carefully. Now the query is functional. 
I just have to add some condition to finish, could you please help me?
When I do that, the result is no longer good : 
where  flag = 1 and state='F' and company='soso'
where I can add my conditions without impacting the result of the request?

Comment: @DavidOl - Those conditions, most likely, should be added as a `WHERE` clause in the **subquery**: `select t.*, row_number().... from test_data t WHERE state = 'F' and company = 'soso'`.